# I have 2 external drives for storage...usb. One refuses to mount automatcally

Tags: automount

Here is the error message...

```
mount:/mnt/usb VenderCo_ProductCode_8428481090229500947-0:0: must be superuser to use mount
```

Comment: The output is in plain language: "*must be superuser to use mount*." Prepend your mount command with sudo.

Comment: @user535733 explaining the output is the easy part. The tricky one is: why does automatically mount and not the other?

Comment: For that, we would need more than just one error message. We would need /etc/fstab and a description of the OP's workflow for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will automatically mount external USB drives provided ... the file system is coherent and clean.

Have the file system of the drive that is not automounted checked and repaired. You can do this using the utility "Disks" that is by default installed in Ubuntu. Select the drive in the left pane, then the partition on the map on the right pane. The partition cannot be mounted. You can, if needed, unmount by clicking the icon with the stop sign (■). If the drive is not mounted, that button will exhibit a start sign (▶) - do *not* click it in that case. Then click the cog icon and select "Check filesystem".

In Disks, you can see the file system if you click the partition (next to "Contents: "). If the file system is ntfs, i.e., the file system of Microsoft Windows, then instead connect the drive to an MS Windows system and have it checked there.